# Question regarding fixed point (integrals)

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  be a continuous function. Show that, if $$\int\limits_0^1 f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t =\frac{1}{2},$$ then $f$ has a fixed point in $[0,1]$, i.e. $\exists x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$.

Comment: Welcome on MSE. Could you please tell us what have you tried and where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Set $g(x)=f(x)-x$. It continuous and s.t. $\int_0^1 g(x)\,\mathrm d x=0$. Your problem is equivalent as proving that $g$ cancel at some point $c\in [0,1]$. Suppose by contradiction that it doesn't, and see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Apply MVT on $[0,1]$ for $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\;dt-\frac{x}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $ g:x\mapsto f\left(x\right)-x $, and $ G:x\mapsto\int_{0}^{x}{g\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x} $, notice that : $$ G\left(1\right)-G\left(0\right)=0 $$

Now you can apply Rolle's theorem to $ G $, which is a $ \mathcal{C}^{1} $ function on $ \left[0,1\right] $.